# Can i able to make my Own SoundBeat Detector in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to implement functionality to make the Visualization effect to play with the Sound.
As per my point of view  may be i have to Implement the Sound Detector in iPhone.
So is there any Functionality available to detect the Sound and also its beat as per Sound results ??

I want to set the detector for bass, trouble and many other things.

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't go looking for trouble.

Comment: But How can i implement it ? Is there any API or anything else that can help me. .  Please reply regarding it. i really need it. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge in IPhone we dont directly have any framework that can give us beats of the sound but what i have found for detecting beats and then make it visually implemented on screen, try the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) of apple. This can help you to implement 3 types of visual implementation... Oscilloscope, FFT, and Sonogram..